# How to get value of ValueMember of datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcombobox, valuemember

Friends, I'm using datagridviewcomboboxcolumn as column index 1 in my datagridview. I've fetched data from access database table and populated the datagridviewcomboboxcolumn by following manner:

```
    for (int i = 0; reader.Read(); i++)
        {
            cmbBusCode.Items.Add(reader["BUSINESS_CODE"] + "-" + reader["BUSINESS_DESCRIPTION"]);
            cmbBusCode.ValueMember = "BUSINESS_CODE";
        }
```

Then I'm writing this:

```
        cmbBusCode.DisplayIndex = 1;
        cmbBusCode.Width = 200;
        cmbBusCode.Name = "Code";
        cmbBusCode.HeaderText = "Code";
```

And adding this column as

```
    dgView.Columns.Add(cmbBusCode);
```

Combobox is being populated and I can select any one from the list. Now when I'm saving data I want to get the ValueMember of the selected item. To get this value I'm using following code but It's giving the string representation of the field "BUSINESS_CODE" not the value..Please help me so that  get ValueMemeber of the selected item..

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgView.Rows)
    {
        string cd = row.Cells["Code"].Value.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The "item" you are adding to the column doesn't have a "BUSINESS_CODE" column (essentially, the item as you add it is simply a string), so that doesn't work.

What you need to do is assign items that contain multiple columns. One must be the `BUSINESS_CODE` column (as it is this column you want to be the value for the underlying field in the `DataGridView`), the other should be a display column that contains the concatenated value you're adding at the moment (`DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`).

Easiest would be to create a typed data set, add a table that contains the two columns I described and fill the table with the data from the data reader.

Then, add the table as the data source for the column.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` instead of a `string` to the `cmbBusCode.Items` collection. You can then specify `Value` in the cell. I'm not sure if this will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Huh? The `cmbBusCode` is the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`! Its `Items` collection is supposed to take a list of items, which are displayed and can be selected. If the objects passed as items contain members that correspond to the values of `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`, the values of these members are display or assigned to the field of the underlying data object. What you're suggesting is *not* worth a try, as this is not how things work...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, yes cmbBusCode is DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and I've populated using the above mentioned code. I wanted to get the corresponding ValueMember for the selected item in the list..But I'm not getting..

Comment: Did you read my answer? Your items do not contain a property that has the name you're assigning to the `ValueMember` property. Read my answer. To give you an analogy: You can write a method named `button_Click` - however, it will not be invoked unless you assign it to a button's `Click` event. You are not getting a value, because you did assign the name of a property to `ValueMember`, but there's nothing of that name in the underlying object.